# I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox 4.3.12 (Windows 7), where do I begin? LAMP?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, lamp

Can anyone direct me to some beginner tutorials so I can learn the basics of Ubuntu 14.04 and what to configure/install?

Furthermore, any good tutorials for installing/configuring LAMP?

Comment: It is a big list, mate, not just at one question I guess. Try to google for tutorials, and next time asking here include what you did and what went wrong.

Comment: The problem is I have no way to tell which guides are good, which aren't, which are outdated, etc. It seems prudent to ask for recommendations from live people

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial, only the apps you need:

http://blog.desdelinux.net/que-hacer-despues-de-instalar-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

To install LAMP you need install synaptic and tasksel

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic tasksel
```

Then when this finish open the synaptic program in menu apps

Menu -> Edit -> Packages by work -> LAMP server select -> Accept -> Apply

:)